# Basic Ruby string handling

Tags: ruby, string, methods

Does giving a

```
idea = gets.reverse
print idea
```

If user inputted 'dog' it would come out 'dog'

But if you did this code...

```
idea = gets.reverse!
print idea
```

Then the string variable being returned would be 'god', right?

Comment: Read more about Ruby methods ending with ! or ? at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/612189/why-are-exclamation-marks-used-in-ruby-methods

Comment: note that `gets` returns a user input string upto and including a newline (`"\n"`), so `idea` will never just be `"dog"`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why not try it:

```
irb(main):001:0> idea = gets.reverse
dog
=> "\ngod"
irb(main):002:0> idea = gets.reverse!
dog
=> "\ngod"
```

Both will return the reversed string. However:

```
irb(main):010:0> idea = gets
dog
=> "dog\n"
irb(main):011:0> idea.reverse
=> "\ngod"
irb(main):012:0> idea
=> "dog\n"
irb(main):013:0> idea.reverse!
=> "\ngod"
irb(main):014:0> idea
=> "\ngod"
```

reverse! will modify the current string while reverse will return a new one.

Answer (score 1):

Why the "print idea" ? The gets methods asks a user for it's input. No other arguments are required.

In that case, whether you're using reverse or reverse! wouldn't change anything.
The reverse method reverses the string and returns the reversed one.
The reverse! method reverses the string, returns the reversed one and changes the original string to the new value.

So if you have :

```
 str = "god"
 rst = str.reverse
 p rst + ' ' + str
```

It'll display "dog god" as the reversed string is only returned and you do not exploit the returned value.

If you have :

```
str = "god"
rst = str.reverse!
p rst + ' ' + str
```

It'll display "dog dog" as the reverse! method reverses the string, returns it and changes the original variable.

Answer (score 1):

`reverse` returns a new reversed string.

```
s = "hello" 
s1 = s.reverse
puts s , s1 
#=> "hello"
#   "olleh"
```

`reverse!` reverses the current string itslef and returns a reference to it.

```
s = "hello" 
s1 = "hello".reverse!
puts s , s1 
#=> "olleh"
#   "olleh"
# Now check that s1 == s2 (Refrerence check)
s1[4] = "k"
puts s , s1
#=> "ollek"
#   "ollek"
```

Answer (score 0):

They both print "god" IMO.

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you're stuck on is this:

1. When does the reverse happen?
2. What gets assigned to the variable `idea`?

The key thing is that everything on the right happens *before* the assignment. So if you chain a bunch of methods on the right, then what gets assigned is the final result of the chain.

Play with it a little in `irb` and see:

```
>> input = gets.chomp.reverse
fooboo
=> "ooboof"
>> input = gets.chomp.reverse.upcase
fooboo
=> "OOBOOF"
```

What might also be tripping you up is that Ruby's string method `reverse` returns a reversed string, but it doesn't actually change the string it's called on. To change the string itself, as others have said, you need the `reverse!` method. This is a pattern in the language. (This can be a gotcha, and there are similar gotchas in other languages. For example `sort @array` in Perl returns a reversed array but doesn't change `@array`'s order.)