# what does an exclamation mark follow with variable mean in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, mongomapper

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why are exclamation marks used in Ruby methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612189/why-are-exclamation-marks-used-in-ruby-methods)

i am reading tutorials for Rails3 with MongoDB

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/MongoDB+Data+Modeling+and+Rails

and i see this 
      key :user_id,   ObjectId
      **timestamps!**
what does the exclamation mark mean??

Thanks.

```
 class Story
  include MongoMapper::Document

  key :title,     String
  key :url,       String
  key :slug,      String
  key :voters,    Array
  key :votes,     Integer, :default => 0
  key :relevance, Integer, :default => 0

  # Cached values.
  key :comment_count, Integer, :default => 0
  key :username,      String

  # Note this: ids are of class ObjectId.
  key :user_id,   ObjectId
  timestamps!

  # Relationships.
  belongs_to :user

  # Validations.
  validates_presence_of :title, :url, :user_id
end
```

Comment: This is tagged `excel` and `syncfusion` ...why?

Comment: In case someone wanted to know what timestamps! was for: 
http://mongomapper.com/documentation/plugins/timestamps.html

Answer (score 0):

in general, when a 'bang' follows a method in Ruby it will change the source.

for example check out the following output:

```
irb(main):007:0> x = 'string'
=> "string"
irb(main):008:0> x
=> "string"
irb(main):009:0> x.capitalize
=> "String"
irb(main):010:0> x
=> "string"
irb(main):011:0> x.capitalize!
=> "String"
irb(main):012:0> x
=> "String"
```

x.capitalize returns "String", but variable x remains lower case. When I add the ! ('bang') to the end var x is modified.

i am not overall familiar with mongodb, but this may shed some light onto the purpose of the bang in ruby.

Comment: Just a note here, the bang used in destructive methods (that is, that change the source), is merely a convention - and Ruby is full of conventions.

Comment: thanks, I am a complete new comer to ruby, but questions like this I like to understand. So I spent some time on it last night, knowing, this topic would likely be closed. Thanks for clearing that up! +1