# What does an ! following the name of a Ruby method signify?

Tags: ruby, syntax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why are exclamation marks used in Ruby methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612189/why-are-exclamation-marks-used-in-ruby-methods)

While looking over some Ruby code I came across this method:

```
def SomeMethod!
    // ...
end
```

**What does the ! following the method name do?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it's just a convention to mark a method as 'more dangerous than others." This could mean that it has a side effect that affects its parameters or maybe its class attributes. It's just a reminder to be careful.

Comment: Yep. That's it. "More dangerous" or "more surprising" than the non-bang method.

Answer (score 1):

By convention it means that the method mutates the state of the class.

Comment: No, that's *not* what the convention means.

Answer (score 1):

The exclamation mark at the end of a method's name means that such a method performs an operation in a more dangerous way than the version of the same method without the `!`.

Notice that you should never ever use `!` if there is not such other method. You can understand `!` as a means to visually differentiate between two otherwise equivalent methods.

Example:

[`Array#flatten`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Array/flatten)

[`Array#flatten!`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Array/flatten%21)

[`Kernel#exit!`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Kernel/exit%21)

[`Kernel#exit`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Kernel/exit)

Comment: +1 for correctly mentioning the fact that bang methods should only exist if there is a corresponding non-bang method. -1 for mentioning mutation: it's not *just* about mutation, it's basically about being "more surprising", which includes, but is not limited to mutation.

Comment: @JörgWMittag: 'surprising' is kind of vague :) Can you give me an example on the MRI where `!` are used to signal something else than mutation of the original data?

Comment: [`Kernel#exit!`](http://RubyDoc.Info/stdlib/core/Kernel:exit!) and [`Process::exit!`](http://RubyDoc.Info/stdlib/core/Process.exit!).