# What does ! mean in front of a method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

What does it mean when the bang method is in front? What is this shorthand for?

```
!post.save
```

Comment: Is it the same as [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/612189/why-are-exclamation-marks-used-in-ruby-methods)? I don't know Ruby.

Comment: @minitech, no, it's not.

Comment: @KL-7: You're right, it's not. I can't believe I didn't notice that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is equivalent to

```
not post.save
```

Usually used in `if` clauses, like:

```
if !post.save               #if the post could not be saved for some reason
   puts 'could not save post!'
end
```

It's because the function save from `ActiveResource::Base` returns `true` if the POST request succeeded and `false` if it didn't. [Read here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveResource/Base.html#method-i-save) for some more information about the function.

Answer (score 6):

It's a negation.  In your example it means to NOT the result of post.save.

if:

```
post.save => true
!post.save => false
```

otherwise:

```
post.save => false
!post.save => true
```