# Naming convention: Why Array#delete has no exclamation mark at the end?

Tags: ruby, naming-conventions

I'm learning Ruby and I've seen that an exclamation mark at the end of a method name by convention means that the method modifies `self` in some way. Why doesn't then `Array#delete` end with an exclamation mark, like `slice!` does, since `delete` deletes an element from `self`? Am I missing something fundamental?

Comment: My guess is because `#delete` can do only delete so there is no need to flag it. Something like `#upper_case` can either be assigned to a newly created object or overwrite the original object at the determination of the use.

Comment: Yes, but #delete with no flag could also return a clone minus the specified element (That's what I expected given the absence of a flag) :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why are exclamation marks used in Ruby methods?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/612189/why-are-exclamation-marks-used-in-ruby-methods)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To quote [Matz](http://www.wobblini.net/bang.txt) (Ruby's chief engineer):

> The bang (!) does not mean "destructive" nor lack of it mean non
>   destructive either.  The bang sign means "the bang version is more
>   dangerous than its non bang counterpart; handle with care".

Since `Array#delete` doesn't have a less-dangerous counterpart, there is no need for the exclamation.

Answer (score 4):

The "bang" methods don't mean that it modifies the receiver. It is an indication of a method that is a more dangerous version of an existing method. See [David A. Black's description](http://dablog.rubypal.com/2007/8/15/bang-methods-or-danger-will-rubyist) of the difference, and the [response to a request](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/2105382) to change Ruby 2.0.

This is a very common misconception. Note the very highly-voted *wrong* answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612189/why-are-exclamation-marks-used-in-ruby-methods).