# Saving the order of a shuffled array in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, shuffle

If I say...

```
a = [1,2,3]
a.shuffle
puts a
```

...it gives [1,2,3]. If instead I say...

```
a=[1,2,3]
a.shuffle!
puts a
```

...it gives me a new order each time I say puts a. So my question is how do I save the order a shuffled array was put into? If it returns [3,1,2] the first time it should keep this order. Does this make sense?

Here is an example of what I'm talking about. Each time I call b I get a different result.

```
> a=[1,2,3]
=> [1, 2, 3]
> b=a.shuffl­e!
=> [1, 3, 2]
> b
=> [1, 2, 3]
> b
=> [2, 1, 3]
> b
=> [1, 3, 2]
> b
=> [3, 2, 1]
```

"b" seems to refer to the function a.shuffle instead of the results of the shuffle itself.

**The answer:**

The problem occured when using the online interpreter on TryRuby.org. Using the interactive Ruby interpreter on my PC gives the correct result. Thanks to everyone for their help!

Comment: `a = [1,2,3]`
`b= a.shuffle puts b` ??

Comment: What do you mean by saving the order? I think it would help if you gave some surrounding code as how you define and call this code e t c.

Comment: It does not give you a new order each time you `puts a`; it gives you a new random order each time you run your code, since that causes it to be `shuffle!`d again.

Comment: I mean if it shuffles the array into [3,1,2] then every time a is called after that it should give [3,1,2].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem occured when using the online interpreter on TryRuby.org. Using the interactive Ruby interpreter on my PC gives the correct result. Thanks to everyone for their help!

Comment: Wow, what a frustrating bug. I'm going to copy this into the question.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need somethinglike this:

```
a = [1,2,3]

b = a.shuffle

puts b
```

Comment: my bad it should be `shuffle` not `shuffled`

Comment: Thanks this does not keep the order a gets shuffled into. Each time b is called it gives a different result.

Answer (score 0):

`a.shuffle` returns a shuffling of `a`, but does not change `a` itself, so you'd need to assign the result to a different variable (or to `a` if that's what you want). You need to call `a.shuffle!` if you want the method to change `a` directly.

See [Why are exclamation marks used in Ruby methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612189/why-are-exclamation-marks-used-in-ruby-methods)

Comment: if I say a.shuffle! it gives a random order for the array each time its called. How do I keep the order the array was shuffled into?

Comment: I guess I'm not sure what you mean. Calling `a.shuffle!` shuffles the array and stores the result back in `a`. What order do you want to keep?

Comment: > a=[1,2,3]
=> [1, 2, 3]
> b=a.shuffl­e!
=> [1, 3, 2]
> b
=> [1, 2, 3]
> b
=> [2, 1, 3]
> b
=> [1, 3, 2]
> b
=> [3, 2, 1]