# How to get detailed error messages from rails console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Say I wish to create a user from console with an email which **already** exists. If I do `User.create(...)`

Because of model validations (*uniqueness in this case*). `create` fails and the output in rails console will say: `rollback transaction` (user is not saved)

For the purpose of testing. Is their a way I can **get the explicit error which triggered the rollback**? In this case it would say something like: "ROLLBACK: email is not unique".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can also do:

```
User.create!
```

The 'bang' will force it to show you the errors without additional steps.

Answer (score 12):

You could do the following in Rails console:

```
>> user = User.new(...)
>> user.save
>> user.errors.messages
```

That way, you know what errors caused `save` to fail.

Comment: Is there any way to get errors for something like `User.create(name: "John")` (i.e. where there was no assignment) ?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean by using "rails console", I hope and this small example is useful for you:

Model Student (student.rb):

```
class Student < ApplicationRecord
  validates :name, presence: true, length: {minimum: 5, maximum: 50}
end
```

And at Rails console ($ rails console) do something like this:

```
> student = Student.create(name:"alba")
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
 => #<Student id: nil, name: "alba">

> student.errors.any?
 => true

> student.errors.full_messages
 => ["Name is too short (minimum is 5 characters)"]
```

Hope this helps.