# Adding a + 1 to count in another table, when a different table has an entry created

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, controller

So I have a table with books and a table with borrowers.  A User borrows a book of choice, and later it is shown on the page who borrowed it and what was borrowed.

Now I also have a column in my books table which is count, to see how many times the book has been borrowed.

Should the code for it go into borrowing controller?   I tried to put it under def create action before.

Did something like `count = Book.find(params[:id]), count = params[:count] + 1`

But this solution seemed to not work, it did't even find the book that I was talking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your borrowers table has association with books table. than you can add a `callback` in `model` `after_create :increase_count_id` and create a method in borrower model

```
def increase_count_id
 self.book.update_column(count: self.book.count + 1)
end
```

Comment: Does not seem to make a +1 still but creates a error when I make a new book: undefined local variable or method `increase_count_id

Comment: I have made the associations in models that books has burrows and burrows belongs to book

Comment: Okay now I get it when borrowing a new book: undefined local variable or method `increase_count_id'    .   But I have the callback written in the borrower model and the action in borrower controller.

Comment: It's like it does not see that I have it defined in my controller. It is written corrently too, cannot be typo.

Comment: the method should also gone too borrower model :)

Comment: Silly me... But now it gives a wrong number of arguments error : wrong number of arguments (1 for 2)    But it has everything needed?

Comment: Nevermind I changed it to :count, self.book and now it works! Thanks alot

Comment: okay change the method code to `book = self.book ` , `book.count = book.count +1` , `book.save`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this:

```
book.increment!(:count, 1)
```

Comment: But why the exclamation mark in the end? I don't understand. Other than that, it is even a nicer solution to my problem!

Comment: ! means update changes in calling object. You can check example over here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/612189/why-are-exclamation-marks-used-in-ruby-methods?answertab=votes#tab-top