# .downcase! syntax shorthand

Tags: ruby

Can someone explain what the difference is between the two pieces of code below? Both feature an `!` at the end. Is the first version just the shorthand?

```
print "Who are you?" 
user_input = gets.chomp.downcase!

print "Who are you?"
user_input = gets.chomp
user_input.downcase!
```

Comment: You don't need bang in the first case, you do need it in the second.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why are exclamation marks used in Ruby methods?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/612189/why-are-exclamation-marks-used-in-ruby-methods)

Comment: @Wooble I don't think it is a dup post. This post has different intention..

Comment: It's important to understand what `downcase` and `downcase!` return when each letter in the string is already lower case: `"Abc".downcase! => "abc"`, `"abc".downcase => "abc"`, `"abc".downcase! => nil`.  Many Ruby methods ending `!` have similar behavior: they return `nil` if no change is made.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Edit**: Having an exclamation point (aka "bang") at the end of a method name in ruby means "handle with care". From Matz himself:

> The bang (!) does not mean "destructive" nor lack of it mean non
>   destructive either.  The bang sign means "the bang version is more
>   dangerous than its non bang counterpart; handle with care".  Since
>   Ruby has a lot of "destructive" methods, if bang signs follow your
>   opinion, every Ruby program would be full of bangs, thus ugly.

(For the full thread, see @sawa's link in the comments.)

For the method in question, `downcase` is making a copy of the given string, modifying that,  and returning that copy as a result. Whereas `downcase!` modifies the string itself.

In the first case, you're modifying the variable stored in `gets.chomp`, in the second you're modifying `user_input`.

Note that if you call `user_input.downcase` on the last line (instead of `user_input.downcase!`) it won't actually change `user_input`, it just returns a copy of the string and makes *the copy* lowercase.

Comment: I was going to ask about BroiSatse's comment that "_You don't need bang in the first case, you do need it in the second_" (why is that the case?) but you answered it.

Comment: This answer is wrong, as well as the accepted answer to the question you linked. The correct answer is: https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/176830#773946.

Comment: Wow, thanks @sawa. I didn't know that was its official definition (which also explains why `Array.push` and `Array.pop` don't have exclamation points at the end). I've updated my answer and referenced your comment in it.