# Self-assignment with !-notation on Ruby hashes

Tags: ruby

I'm familiar with Python and Java, and am trying to learn Ruby to broaden my scope a bit.

I'm not quite sure how to conceptualise the "!-notation" of self-assignment. In case I'm not using the right words to describe this, compare:

```
foo = 'Hello World!'
foo = foo.downcase
```

and

```
foo = 'Hello World!'
foo.downcase!
```

Both end up with foo reading `'hello world!'`. It seems, then, that `foo.<method>!` is short-hand for `foo = foo.<method>`.

However, this doesn't seem to be universally true. When trying to call sort-by on a hash `frequencies`, for example, the suggested method is:

```
frequencies = frequencies.sort_by { |word, freq|
  freq
}
```

which works. If, however, I try:

```
frequencies.sort_by! { |word, freq|
  freq
}
```

I get

```
undefined method `sort_by!' for {<the_contents_of_my_hash>}:Hash
```

Is !-notation (what is that properly called, by the way?) only available on strings and arrays? Or is there some deeper concept I'm missing?

Comment: Probably duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/612189/why-are-exclamation-marks-used-in-ruby-methods. In short, methods ending with an exclamation point will modify the object itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Ruby, the characters `?` and `!` are allowed in method names. It's not a special operator are anything. It's a Ruby convention that methods that are considered to perform "dangerous" operations, like modifying the calling collection (instead of returning a new collection), or throwing an exception on an error instead of returning `nil` or `false`, often have a `!` suffix.

However, not all methods have a `!` version. [`sort_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by), for example, doesn't have one, if you look at the documentation.

`!` methods aren't only available on string and arrays. You can define them on anything.

Comment: Gotcha. I had naively assumed that it was a property of the language, rather than an explicitly added optional version of some methods. Thanks for clearing that up!

Comment: @scubbo also worth noting, methods that end with `?` usually, if not always, return boolean values. Also, methods that end with `=` are used as setters, for assigning to properties.