# Ruby - What's the difference between a method with and without an exclamation point?

Tags: ruby, sorting

For example, I've checked the documentation on certain methods, like sort. And it looks like the only difference between `.sort` and `.sort!` is that one sorts `self` in place and the other returns an array. I'm a little unclear on what that means  - they seem to effectively do the same thing.

Can anyone help me understand this a little better?

Comment: Possible Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/612189/why-are-exclamation-marks-used-in-ruby-methods - Basically, methods with a ! modify the object, where as the others return a modified version.

Comment: with/without side-effect (changes the original subject vs. returns a new one).

Comment: Thanks Greg - this explains it succinctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### When to Use Bang Methods

Technically, the exclamation point (or bang) doesn't *intrinsically* mean anything. It's simply an allowable character in the method name. In practice, however, so-called bang methods generally:

- Changed objects in-place. For example, `#sort!` sorts self in place, while `#sort` returns a *new* array created by sorting self.
- Some bang methods return nil if no changes were made, which can cause problems with method chains. For example:

  ```
  'foo'.sub 'x', 'y'
  # => "foo"
  'foo'.sub! 'x', 'y'
  #=> nil
  ```

Use bang methods when you want to mark a method as creating notable side effects, producing destructive operations, or otherwise requiring additional caution or attention. This is largely by convention, though, and you *could* make all your methods bang methods if you were so inclined.

Comment: Thanks CodeGnome. This helps a lot. I think I understand it now.

Answer (score 1):

Methods with a bang(!) are meant to signify a little more caution is required. So, either modification in place vs. not in place (if you are modifying the object in place - you better be sure that you really want to), or in other cases like find_by and find_by! (see [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find_by-21)) where one causes an exception if no record is found and one doesn't cause an exception.

Can you guess which one does and which one does not cause an exception?

Answer (score -1):

The methods with the exclamation point alter the actual object they're called on, where as the methods without will just return a new object that has been manipulated.
i.e.

```
pizza = 'pepperoni'
pizza.capitalize
```

Now the pizza variable will still equal 'pepperoni'.
If we then call

```
pizza.capitalize!
```

The pizza variable will now equal 'Pepperoni'