# Hartl Tutorial Unable to Follow Users

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am on chapter 11 of Michael Hartl's tutorial and unable to follow users. I click the follow button but nothing happens. I've went over that section over and over, copy and pasted the code. It still doesn't work.

Here is the code:

relationships_controller.rb

```
class RelationshipsController < ApplicationController
before_action :signed_in_user

def create
@user = User.find(params[:relationship][:followed_id])
current_user.follow!(@user)
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to @user }
  format.js
end
end

def destroy
@user = Relationship.find(params[:id]).followed
current_user.unfollow!(@user)
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to @user }
  format.js
end
end
end
```

create.js.erb

```
$("#follow_form").html("<%= escape_javascript(render('users/unfollow')) %>")
$("#followers").html('<%= @user.followers.count %>')
```

destroy.js.erb

```
$("#follow_form").html("<%= escape_javascript(render('users/follow')) %>")
$("#followers").html('<%= @user.followers.count %>')
```

_follow.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(current_user.relationships.build(followed_id: @user.id),
         remote: true) do |f| %>
<div><%= f.hidden_field :followed_id %></div>
<%= f.submit "Follow", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

_unfollow.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(current_user.relationships.find_by(followed_id: @user.id),
         html: { method: :delete },
         remote: true) do |f| %>
<%= f.submit "Unfollow", class: "btn btn-large" %>
<% end %>
```

_follow_form.html.erb

```
<% unless current_user?(@user) %>
<div id="follow_form">
<% if current_user.following?(@user) %>
<%= render 'unfollow' %>
<% else %>
<%= render 'follow' %>
<% end %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Can you post server log generated?

Comment: I found that I did not use create in the follow! method in user.rb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing your logs, this is a game of speculation

--

However, there are a number of things to look into.

**Create**

Firstly, you need to make sure your `create` action can actually perform what you want. I notice there's a method `.follow!` included:

```
def create
    @user = User.find(params[:relationship][:followed_id])
    current_user.follow!(@user)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to @user }
      format.js
    end
end
```

Since you're using a [`bang operator`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612189/why-are-exclamation-marks-used-in-ruby-methods), it generally means it will perform a function on the object itself (or at the time of calling). To this degree, you need to ensure you have the `.follow!` instance method in your `User` model

I would expect the following:

```
#app/models/user.rb
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :relationships 

   def follow!(friend)
       self.relationships.create({follower_id = friend.id})
   end
end
```

--

**Forms**

As you're using [`form_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html), you'll want to make sure you're calling the correct routes. I notice Hartl doesn't create an `ActiveRecord Object` before trying to populate the `form_for` - meaning this could cause an issue.

Since you're using a `partial`, I actually understand why this has been done. However, it could be the case that the form is not hitting the right `action`, or it's not sending the params you want

Although I'd love to elaborate on this, I cannot without seeing the logs

--

**Ajax**

Finally, you may wish to consider the response from Ajax.

I notice you're using the `.js.erb` method to perform an action when you've sent a `remote` request. Perhaps the functionality of these files is incorrect?

This could be a problem - if you don't see any other issue with your system (IE your `routes` and `controller` checks out), you'll want to ensure the `.js.erb` files are not messing up.

Again, this would be highlighted in your logs :)

Comment: I found that I used find_by instead of create for the follow! method in user.rb. Thanks for your help!