# Ruby - method changes input variable value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new to Ruby and I'm having trouble understanding what's happening in this method.

I make this call in a Rails controller -

```
@arr = SomeClass.find_max_option(params[:x], @pos, params[:y], some_var)
```

I'm trying to return the value to `@arr`, which happens successfully, but manipulations I make to **`@pos`**  within that method are being brought back as well; the value of `@pos` changes when I'm only trying to get the value for `@arr`.

Here's more details on the method

```
#before going into the method
 @pos = [a,b]

def self.find_max_option(x, pos, y, some_var)

pos.collect! { |element|
    (element == b) ? [c,d] : element
    }
  end

#new value of pos = [a, [c,d]] which is fine for inside in this method

... #some calculations not relevant to this question, but pos gets used to generate some_array

return some_array
```

But when the method is finished and gets back to the controller, the value of `@pos` is now [a,[c,d]] as well.

What's going on here? I thought that `pos` would be treated separately from `@pos` and the value wouldn't carry back. As a workaround I just created a new local variable within that method, but I'd like to know what this is happening

```
#my workaround is to not modify the pos variable
pos_groomed = pos.collect { |element|
    (element == b) ? [c,d] : element
    }
  end
```

Comment: you are passing `@pos` as an argument this means the `pos` is a reference to `@pos`. you could set `pos = pos.dup` prior to the `collect!` or just use non-destructive `collect`. Your code is not exactly straight forward since you are returning a variable that does not exist

Comment: I'm sorry for the noob question, but this is standard for all Ruby methods? Making a change to the arguments passed in within the method propagate up? All arguments are in/out by default? I don't remember this happening in Java.

Comment: Don't be sorry, this is not a noob question, and even if it was, you shouldn't be sorry. Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1872110/is-ruby-pass-by-reference-or-by-value it will help you with this topic.

Comment: Major Major - are you defining any reader/accessors? Chances are you think you have a local variable named pos and you are really calling a reader method named pos.

Comment: This would most definitely happen in Java too.  If you, for example, modified the contents of a passed-in List.

Comment: I don't believe this is related to reader/accessor methods, the @pos variable comes from web parameters and the find_max_option method is solely to return an array. I'll get a Ruby book and read more into how it all works together, I just thought arguments were a one-way street.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using `collect!`, just use `collect` (without the !). So, rewrite your method as:

```
def self.find_max_option(x, pos, y, some_var)
  pos.collect { |element|
    (element == b) ? [c,d] : element
  }
end
```

When using the `!` version of `collect`, you are replacing each element with the value returned by the block. However, when using `collect` **without** `!`, a new array is created, and the object where collect is being called it doesn't get changed. See the docs:

[collect!](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Array.html#method-i-collect-21) vs [collect](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Array.html#method-i-collect)

Using `!` at the end of a method name is a common practice in Ruby. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612189/why-are-exclamation-marks-used-in-ruby-methods) is related and would be worth taking a look.

Comment: I still need the ``pos`` altered to use later in the method (I didn't show the entire thing, just the relevant part), so to use pos.collect I would need to declare a new variable with it like I did in my workaround, right? The issue was more-so why is ``@pos`` being altered as well.

Comment: As a note on this answer, the ruby convention is that any method with a ! is going to have "unexpected side effects". Most often a ! will change the object that is calling it, but sometimes it has other side effects such as exit! which quits without calling any exit handlers. When using a ! method, always consult the docs and make sure you understand what "else" is happening.

Comment: You would need to do a dup as @engineersmnky has suggested in the comment or assign that collect to another variable in the method (like you did with pos_groomed), and use that from then on.

Comment: @MajorMajor also just because I was reference here please also remember that `dup` will make a copy of the outside container but if you are manipulating items inside they will still hold their references. e.g. if you change `a` inside `dup` will not help. For a single dimensional array you could use `.map(&:dup)` which will create a new Array where the objects inside are copies of the original but anything more gets into `deep_dup`ing.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the destructive version of collect.
Destructive methods change the object on which the method is called, while non-destructive methods return new objects.

Ruby developers tend to call these methods 'bang methods', because the convention is that destructive methods have the ! suffix.

```
pos.collect! # changes pos and returns pos
pos.collect  # creates a new object
```

Your workaround only works because you use the non-destructive collect, while the original code uses collect!

```
pos.collect do |element|
 (element == b) ? [c,d] : element
end
```

Should work just fine.

As to why the object changes outside of the method:

In ruby, when you pass an argument to a method, you are actually passing the reference to the object.
So passing an array into a method doesn't make a copy, but simply passes the reference to original array. 
There is no way to 'pass by value' but you can create a copy yourself with dup or clone, if you really have to.

Comment: I would be careful saying 'you are passing a reference to that object'. That is not true in Ruby. Ruby is strictly pass by value.

Comment: Yes, you are right, it's pass by value, but the value is a reference to an object. It's a bit tricky

Comment: I look at it this way: 'Variables are references to objects'.

Comment: Your last paragraph was extremely helpful in understanding what's going on here, thanks.