# Change attributte value in before_update callback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, callback

I try to change `attribute_1` value, when I detect `attribute_2` is changed and about to get updated.

The object gets updated but the set `attribute_1` value is not persisting though, why?

```
before_update :check_attribute2_change

def check_attribute_2_change
  if attribute_2_changed?
      attribute_1 = nil
  end
end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
before_update :check_attribute2_change

def check_attribute_2_change
  self.attribute_1 = nil if attribute_2_changed?      
end
```

Comment: I didn't know that `self` was so important.

Comment: `self` here is important to indicate that attribute_1 is actually an attribute of the instance object that you are referring to. Without`self` it was taking `attribute_1` as a variable and hence you were not seeing the results. Hope that clears the reason :)

Comment: The if can also go in the callback declaration like this:

`before_update :remove_attribute_1, if: :attribute_2_changed?  

def remove_attribute_1
  self.attribute_1 = nil
end`

Answer (score 0):

If you are on model, call:

```
save!
```

You code will look like this:

```
before_update :check_attribute2_change

def check_attribute_2_change
  if attribute_2_changed?
      attribute_1 = nil
      save!
  end
end
```

Note that "before_update" callback, is called before your object is saved (persisted) on database. When you change one more attribute at this stage, you need to save it.

Comment: Trying your code I get this error message: "stack level too deep". I don't know if it's because I'm using the `update` method (and not `save`) in the controller.

Comment: @Numbers... Sorry,

Remove "self." and put only "save"

I will update my answer

Comment: I am doubtful if `save` would work since it will again trigger a before_update callback. Also we generally avoid using `!(bang)` version. See this question: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/612189/why-are-exclamation-marks-used-in-ruby-methods/612653#612653)

Comment: @AaditiJain I made a confusion with after_save :)