# Ruby Array mutation confusion?

Tags: arrays, ruby, ienumerable

I'm trying to get very comfortable with all of the array methods and enumerables in Ruby, but I don't understand why some don't mutate and others do. For instance, is there a difference between:

```
def double(array)
  array.map {|x| x * 2}
end
```

and

```
def double(array)
  return array.map! {|x| x * 2}
end
```

Also, when I tried to call

```
 b.select{|x| x.even?}
```

where b is an array of integers, it did not change, but

```
  b = b.select{|x| x.even?} OR
 .delete_if
```

did seem to mutate it.

Is

```
a.each do |word|
 word.capitalize!
end
```

the same as

```
a.map do |word|
 word.capitalize
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a rule of thumb, [ruby methods that end in `!` will mutate the value they are called on](https://stackoverflow.com/a/612196/1810460), and methods without will return a mutated copy.

See here the documentation for [`map` vs `map!`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-map) and [`capitalize` vs `capitalize!`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-capitalize)

Also note that `b = b.select{|x| x.even?}` is not mutating the list `b`, but is rather calling `b.select` to create an entirely new list, and assigning that list to `b`. Note the difference:

In this, `b` is the same object, just changed:

```
$ irb
@irb(main):001:0> b = [1,2,3]
=> [1, 2, 3]
@irb(main):002:0> b.object_id
=> 69853754998860
@irb(main):003:0> b.select!{|x| x.even?}
=> [2]
@irb(main):004:0> b.object_id
=> 69853754998860
```

But in this, `b` is now an entirely new object:

```
$ irb
@irb(main):001:0> b = [1,2,3]
=> [1, 2, 3]
@irb(main):002:0> b.object_id
=> 70171913541500
@irb(main):003:0> b = b.select{|x| x.even?}
=> [2]
@irb(main):004:0> b.object_id
=> 70171913502160
```

Comment: Typo: 'capitalze!' should be 'capitalize!'.  Also, the example is fine, but the select can be made even more concise with: b.select(&:even?)

Comment: more concise, yes, but less clear; OP was confused about the nature of the difference between two similarly-named method calls, throwing a new concept like method proccing at them isn't going to do anything but confuse them further. Thanks for the typo catch!

Answer (score 1):

> is there a difference between:
>
> def double(array)   array.map {|x| x * 2} end and
>
> def double(array)   return array.map! {|x| x * 2} end

Yes. The first one returns a new array. The second one modifies the original array, and returns it.

> Is
>
> a.each do |word|  word.capitalize! end the same as
>
> a.map do |word|  word.capitalize end

No. The first one modifies the elements in the array, and returns the original array. The second one returns a new array filled with new strings.