# Ruby `downcase!` returns `nil`

Tags: ruby

With this code:

```
input = gets.chomp.downcase!
puts input
```

if there is at least one uppercase letter in the input, the input will be put on screen, freed of its uppercases. But if the input has no uppercase letter, it will put `nil`, like if nothing was written.

I want my input to be fully downcased; if it is a string with no uppercase letter, it should return the same string.

I thought about something like this:

```
input = gets.chomp
if input.include(uppercase) then input.downcase! end
```

But this doesn't work. I hope someone has an idea on how I should do this.

Comment: A lot of these dark mysteries are explained by *reading the documentation*. That's what it's there for. This is a reasonable question, but it's also one you could've answered yourself.

Comment: The correct way to use `downcase!` is: `input = gets.chomp` then `input.downcase!` and finally `puts input`

Comment: Can you explain which specific part of the documentation is unclear to you? That way, the Ruby developers can improve the documentation to help future Rubyists.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Can someone explain the LOGIC of why "whopper".downcase! returns nil rather than just "whopper"? Or is this question worth making a new post for?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the docs for **String**:
(emphasis is mine added)

> **downcase**
>
> **Returns a copy of str** with all uppercase letters replaced with their lowercase counterparts. The operation is locale
>   insensitive—only characters “A” to “Z” are affected. Note: case
>   replacement is effective only in ASCII region.
>
> **downcase!**
>
> Downcases the contents of str, **returning nil if no changes were made**. Note: case replacement is effective only in ASCII
>   region.

Basically it says that **downcase!** (with exclamation mark) will return `nil` if there is no uppercase letters.

To fix your program:

```
input = gets.chomp.downcase
puts input
```

Hope that helped!

Comment: By the way: the documentation you quoted is outdated. As of Ruby 2.4, `String#downcase` supports full Unicode.

Comment: @JörgWMittag is 2.4 released? I'm still using 2.3. I should really get around to installing RVM.

Comment: Yes, it was released 4 weeks ago. Releases are always on Christmas Day.

Answer (score 5):

This will work:

```
input = gets.chomp.downcase
puts input
```

---

**String#downcase**

Returns a modified string and leaves the original unmodified.

```
str = "Hello world!"
str.downcase # => "hello world!"
str          # => "Hello world!"
```

**String#downcase!**

Modifies the original string, returns `nil` if no changes were made or returns the new string if a change was made.

```
str = "Hello world!"
str.downcase! # => "hello world!"
str           # => "hello world!"
str.downcase! # => nil
```

**! (bang) methods**

It's common for Ruby methods with `!` / non-`!` variants to behave in a similar manner. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612189/why-are-exclamation-marks-used-in-ruby-methods) for an in-depth explanation why.

Answer (score 1):

The reason that `downcase!` returns nil is so you know whether or not the object was changed. If you're assigning the modified string to another variable, like you are here, you should use `downcase` instead (without the bang `!`).

If you're not familiar, the standard library bang methods typically act on the receiver directly. That means this:

```
foo = "Hello"
foo.downcase!
foo #=> "hello"
```

Versus this:

```
foo = "Hello"
bar = foo.downcase
foo #=> "Hello"
bar #=> "hello"
```

Comment: "the standard library bang methods typically act on the caller directly" – Do you have any example of this? Many bang methods mutate the *receiver*, some have other "interesting" effects (e.g. `Process::exit!` vs `Process::exit`), but I am not aware of any that act on the caller. In fact, barring deep metaprogramming magic, getting access to the caller at all is pretty much impossible.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Whoops. Silly mistake. Fixed.