# Destructive string assignment

Tags: ruby, string, variable-assignment

In this code,

```
def string_assignment_original_name(name)
  save_name = name
  name.upcase!
  name
end
```

if `name = "Bob"`, the output will be `"BOB"`. Meanwhile in this code,

```
def string_assignment_save_name(name)
  save_name = name
  name.upcase!
  save_name
end
```

if `name = "Bob"`, the output is also `"BOB"`.

Why is this the case?

Comment: Read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612189/why-are-exclamation-marks-used-in-ruby-methods

Comment: `save_name = name` is the key here.

Comment: Why not? .......

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ruby variables are basically "object references" which is a sort of pointer internally. Both `name` and `save_name` refer to the same object both before and after your in-place modification.

Look at the result of `name.object_id` and `save_name.object_id` to see how this plays out, as that method is a window into what's going on internally:

```
name = "bob"
name.object_id
# => ...2980

save_name = name
save_name.object_id
# => ...2980

name.upcase!
name.object_id
# => ...2980
```

Now if you duplicate the object via a method like `.dup` or `.clone`, or if you create a whole new string through some other process, then it's a new object:

```
name = name.downcase
name.object_id
# => ...8480
```

Now you've got two objects in play:

```
name.object_id
# => ...8480
save_name.object_id
# => ...2980
```

These `object_id` values are for all intents random but are unique per object instance. If two objects have the same `object_id` value they are the same object.†

<sub>† Technically objects can override their `object_id` method to return something else but this is rare.</sub>