# Shouldn't force_encoding be force_encoding! in ruby?

Tags: ruby

I'm just wondering if the String method `force_encoding`, since it changes the encoding of the given string, and not a copy of it, rather should be named `force_encoding!`

Update to clarify what kind of answer's I'm after: 
Is there some convention or general idiosyncracy of ruby which I am missing here, which may explain the seemingly inconsistent naming?

Comment: I doubt it’s a good question for SO. Maybe you’d better ask on some ruby forum.

Comment: There are several non-bang methods which modify the receiver: `String#clear`, `String#concat`, `String#delete`, `String#insert`, `String#replace`, `String#setbyte`

Comment: ...While I'm here, let's also highlight the *other* common misconception: predicate methods (i.e. ending in `?`) *usually, but do not always* mean "returns `true` or `false`"). Technically, they just mean "returns truthy or falsey". For example, `File.size?` either returns the file size (an integer) or `nil` (if the file does not exist).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Contrary to popular belief, and many misleading beginners' ruby guides, bang methods **do not** mean "this method mutates the object".

That's *usually* the case, but not always.

A better interpretation of the *convention* for bang methods is "this is a more dangerous version of its non-bang counterpart".

For example:

- `String#gsub!` is the "dangerous" version of `String#gsub`, since it mutates the object.
- `ActiveRecord::Base#save!` is the "dangerous" version of `ActiveRecord::Base#save`, since it *raises an exception* if validation fails.
- `exit!` is the "dangerous" version of `exit`, since the former exits immediately, whereas the latter actually [raises an exception](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-exit) - which *could* be rescued elsewhere in the code.

Furthermore, note that there are plenty of ruby methods that *do* mutate the object but **aren't bang methods**. For example, `String#delete` and `Array#pop`.

[This article](http://davidablack.net/dablog.html#2007/8/15/bang-methods-or-danger-will-rubyist) goes into more detail on the matter.

---

So, (warning: opinionated response!) I would argue that:

1. It's fine for `String#force_encoding` to be a non-bang method. This is not completely inconsistent with other conventions in the language.
2. *If* it were a bang method, it would require a non-bang counterpart for consistency.
3. I, personally, don't think the use case for a non-mutating `String#force_encoding` is common enough to warrant its creation. In the rare case that you actually wanted to do this, you could write: `string.dup.force_encoding(...)`.

Comment: ...And if you disagree with my opinion about point 3, why not raise a feature request for a future ruby version? It could also be a fun/simple task to write a ruby gem that changes the language behaviour... But I suspect doing so would break all sorts of things in a large project! Maybe it could be implemented as a refinement.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This was the kind of answer I was hoping to get. As I suspected there might be a subtle reason behind it. And clearing up the misconception was really helpful. TIL something new. :)

Answer (score 2):

Despite the common assumption, bang methods do not necessarily mutate their receiver, nor can you assume that non-bang methods don't mutate their receiver. Examples for that are e.g. `Array#pop`, `Array#clear`.

Instead, methods with a trailing bang indicate that the method is "dangerous" in some way. Especially in the Ruby core, it is generally expected that for each bang method there is always a less dangerous non-bang method.

See the answers to a more generic question on that topic for more details: [Why are exclamation marks used in Ruby methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/612653/421705)