# After using .flatten, identical strings aren't equal to each other

Tags: arrays, ruby, multidimensional-array

Good evening. I have a nested name array. Calling specific indices and using `==` returns true. After using `.flatten` , using `==` on the same values returns false.

```
name_array
=> [["Theo", "Peter Jr.", "Lucky"], ["Theo", "Peter Jr.", "Ms. K"], ["Queenie", "Andrew", "Ms. K", "Alex"], ["Queenie", "Alex"]]
irb(main):044:0> name_array[0][0]
=> "Theo"
irb(main):045:0> name_array[1][0]
=> "Theo"
irb(main):046:0> name_array[0][0] == name_array[1][0]
=> true
irb(main):047:0> name_array.flatten
=> ["Theo", "Peter Jr.", "Lucky", "Theo", "Peter Jr.", "Ms. K", "Queenie", "Andrew", "Ms. K", "Alex", "Queenie", "Alex"]
irb(main):048:0> name_array[0] == name_array[3]
=> false
```

The end goal here is to return an array of unique names.
My first instinct was to use `.uniq` but that ends up returning the original nested array. It should be noted I first got this nested array by converting a nested hash to an array then adding the array values to name_array.

```
irb(main):051:0> name_array.flatten
=> ["Theo", "Peter Jr.", "Lucky", "Theo", "Peter Jr.", "Ms. K", "Queenie", "Andrew", "Ms. K", "Alex", "Queenie", "Alex"]
irb(main):052:0> name_array.uniq
=> [["Theo", "Peter Jr.", "Lucky"], ["Theo", "Peter Jr.", "Ms. K"], ["Queenie", "Andrew", "Ms. K", "Alex"], ["Queenie", "Alex"]]
```

Comment: What is your expected output? Because IMO all arrays are different therefore all arrays should be returned. I am wrong? Do you expect a different result?

Comment: Ruby always returns the value of the last-executed function, and this is what `irb` prints. When you do `name_array.flatten` it returns a new flattened array, `irb` prints the result. The flattened array isn't assigned to any variable and gets discarded as soon as it goes out of scope. `name_array` still holds the original value. Use `name_array.flatten.uniq` to get the result you want. But you still need to assign the result to a variable...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem here is that [`#flatten`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Array/flatten) returns a new array and not change the original one.

to solve it you have 2 ways:

1. Define a new variable with an array that returns after the call of `#flatten`

```rb
flatten_array = name_array.flatten

flatten_array[0] == flatten_array[3]
=> true
```

2. Use [`#flatten!`](https://apidock.com/ruby/v2_5_5/Array/flatten%21), that change original array:

```rb
name_array.flatte!

name_array[0] == name_array[3]
```

the same with [`#uniq`](https://apidock.com/ruby/v2_5_5/Array/uniq), to change original use: [`#uniq!`](https://apidock.com/ruby/v2_5_5/Array/uniq%21)

Summary: to solve what you need:

```rb
name_array.flatten!
name_array.uniq # or .uniq!

# OR

flatten_array = name_array.flatten
flatten_array.uniq # or .uniq!
```

and one more trick, using: [`#inject`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/inject) and [`#|`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-7C)

```rb
name_array.inject(&:|) # will do the same as name_array.flatten.uniq
```

P.S. it's second your question with the very same problem, I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/612196/4057366) might help you to understand how it works ":)
In general: methods with an exclamation mark(!) will change your original variable value, methods without an exclamation mark(!) will return you a new value