# if/elsif/else return behavior difference between Ruby and Python

Tags: python, ruby, algorithm, sorting, quickselect

I am trying to convert a quickselect from Ruby to Python. The Ruby code is as follows:

```rb
class SortableArray
    attr_reader :array
    def initialize(array)
        @array = array
    end
    def quickselect!(kth_lowest_value, left_index, right_index)
        # If we reach a base case - that is, that the subarray has one cell,
        # we know we've found the value we're looking for:
        if right_index - left_index <= 0
            return @array[left_index]
        end
        # Partition the array and grab the index of the pivot:
        pivot_index = partition!(left_index, right_index)
        # If what we're looking for is to the left of the pivot:
        if kth_lowest_value < pivot_index
            # Recursively perform quickselect on the subarray to
            # the left of the pivot:
            quickselect!(kth_lowest_value, left_index, pivot_index - 1)
            # If what we're looking for is to the right of the pivot:
        elsif kth_lowest_value > pivot_index
            # Recursively perform quickselect on the subarray to
            # the right of the pivot:
            quickselect!(kth_lowest_value, pivot_index + 1, right_index)
        else # if kth_lowest_value == pivot_index
            # if after the partition, the pivot position is in the same spot
            # as the kth lowest value, we've found the value we're looking for
            return @array[pivot_index]
        end
    end
    
    def partition!(left_pointer, right_pointer)
        # We always choose the right-most element as the pivot.
        # We keep the index of the pivot for later use:
        pivot_index = right_pointer
        # We grab the pivot value itself:
        pivot = @array[pivot_index]
        # We start the right pointer immediately to the left of the pivot
        right_pointer -= 1
        while true
            # Move the left pointer to the right as long as it
            # points to value that is less than the pivot:
            while @array[left_pointer] < pivot do
                left_pointer += 1
            end
            # Move the right pointer to the left as long as it
            # points to a value that is greater than the pivot:
            while @array[right_pointer] > pivot do
                right_pointer -= 1
            end
            # We've now reached the point where we've stopped
            # moving both the left and right pointers.
            # We check whether the left pointer has reached
            # or gone beyond the right pointer. If it has,
            # we break out of the loop so we can swap the pivot later
            # on in our code:
            if left_pointer >= right_pointer
                break
            # If the left pointer is still to the left of the right
            # pointer, we swap the values of the left and right pointers:
            else
                @array[left_pointer], @array[right_pointer] = @array[right_pointer], @array[left_pointer]
            # We move the left pointer over to the right, gearing up
            # for the next round of left and right pointer movements:
                left_pointer += 1
            end
        end
        # As the final step of the partition, we swap the value
        # of the left pointer with the pivot:
        @array[left_pointer], @array[pivot_index] = @array[pivot_index], @array[left_pointer]
        # We return the left_pointer for the sake of the quicksort method
        # which will appear later in this chapter:
        return left_pointer
    end
end



array = [0, 50, 20, 10, 60, 30]
sortable_array = SortableArray.new(array)
p sortable_array.quickselect!(1, 0, array.length - 1)
```

When I converted it into python it only worked when I put a `return` after the if and elif conditions (lines 28 and 30) like so:

```py
def partition(left_p, right_p, arr=[]):
    pivot_index = right_p
    pivot = arr[pivot_index]
    right_p -= 1

    while True:
        while arr[left_p] < pivot:
            left_p += 1
        while arr[right_p] > pivot:
            right_p -= 1

        if left_p >= right_p:
            break
        else:
            arr[left_p], arr[right_p] = arr[right_p], arr[left_p]
            left_p += 1

    arr[left_p], arr[pivot_index] = arr[pivot_index], arr[left_p]
    return left_p

def quickselect(kth_lowest_value, left_index, right_index, arr=[]):
    print(arr)
    if right_index - left_index <= 0:
        return arr[left_index]
    pivot_index = partition(left_index, right_index, arr)

    if kth_lowest_value < pivot_index:
        return quickselect(kth_lowest_value, left_index, pivot_index-1, arr)
    elif kth_lowest_value > pivot_index:
        return quickselect(kth_lowest_value, pivot_index+1, right_index, arr)
    else:
        print(f"item = {arr[pivot_index]}")
        return arr[pivot_index]


array = [200, 97, 100, 101, 211, 107, 63, 123, 11, 34]
index = quickselect(6, 0, len(array)-1, array)
print(index)
```

Why does it work in Ruby without the return? Is it because it is inside a class?

Comment: Ruby doesn't need `return`, all funcs just return whatever the expression last evaluated was, so all of the `if`-`elsif`-`else` branches implicitly return their value. `return @array[pivot_index]` has an unnecessary (and misleading) `return`. Also, it seems strange to use `!` for a function that returns a value. `!` usually denotes "in-place" in Ruby.

Comment: @ggorlen, great, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Ruby code isn't very idiomatic. The last `return` in the `if`-`elsif`-`else` branch is a red herring and inconsistent with the other branches in the conditional chain. There's an implicit `return` on the other branches in the `if`-`elsif`-`else` chain as well.

To generalize the above idea, in all Ruby functions and methods, if control reaches the end of the function without encountering a `return`, the return value is that of the last expression evaluated. In a conditional chain, that'd be whichever branch was taken.

A minimal example is:

```rb
def foo(n)
  if n == 0
    "zero"
  elsif n == 1
    "one"
  else
    "something else"
  end
end

puts foo(0) # => zero
puts foo(1) # => one
puts foo(2) # => something else
```

Adding `return`s to any or all of the above branches does nothing to change the behavior, and is normally omitted.

Python's implicit return, on the other hand, is always `None`. Returning a non-`None` value involves using an explicit `return` (["explicit is better than implicit"](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) I guess?).

```py
def foo(n):
    if n == 0:
        return "zero"
    elif n == 1:
        return "one"
    else:
        return "something else"

print(foo(0)) # => zero
print(foo(1)) # => one
print(foo(2)) # => something else
```

Another note about the Ruby code: usually `!` after a function/method name is used for [in-place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612189/why-are-exclamation-marks-used-in-ruby-methods) algorithms, that is, ones that modify the input, or otherwise more dangerous versions of non-bang methods. Since `quickselect!` doesn't modify any class state, it's confusing that it has a bang.